# If $G$ is a group of an even order, show that there exists an element of $G$ of order 2.

Tags: group-theory

Im not sure where to start. I first assume $|G|<{\infty}$ and $|G|=2k$ with $k\ge{1}$. Then take some element $g\in{G}$, but I can't see what I can show from the assumptions.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: No I do not know this theorem, is there an elementary way of proving the statement

Comment: Yes, there is, via the equivalence relation $x \sim y \iff x=y $ or $y=x^{-1}$. Which classes have only $1$ element in them? What does it mean for other elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have :
$$G:=A\sqcup(G\backslash A),  $$
with $A:=\{x\in G,x^{-1}=x\}.$

Since $x\in G\backslash A$   iff   $x^{-1}\in G\backslash A$, we have : $|G\backslash A|\equiv 0\pmod 2$, so $|A|\equiv 0\pmod 2$

Moreover, $e\in A$ and $|A|$ is even, so $|A|\ge 2$, and you can find $x\in G\backslash\{e\}$ with $x=x^{-1}$, i.e $x^2=e$. $\blacksquare$